# yo @microsoft/sharepoint Cannot Build webpart project for Sharepoint 2019 On Premesis

Tags: spfx

I was editing webparts for 2019 SP.  I then found some errors on sHTTPclient

```
Argument of type 'import("node_modules/@microsoft/sp-http/dist/index-internal").SPHttpClientConfiguration' is not assignable to parameter of type 'import("node_modules/@microsoft/sp-webpart-base/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-http/lib/spHttpClient/SPHttpClientConfiguration").default'.
  Property 'flags' is protected but type 'SPHttpClientConfiguration' is not a class derived from 'SPHttpClientConfiguration'.
```

So I decided to create sharepoint 2019 default project from a generator to investigate the installed packages and compare to the current webpart, however when I create a project from yo @microsoft/sharepoint 2019 on premesis
I got these error

```
Error - typescript - src/webparts/2019/2019WebPart.ts(10,12): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'from'.
Error - typescript - src/webparts/2019/2019WebPart.ts(17,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'WebPart'.
Error - typescript - src/webparts/2019/2019WebPart.ts(17,41): error TS2365: Operator '>' cannot be applied to types 'boolean' and '{ render(): void; onDispose(): void; readonly dataVersion: Version; getPropertyPaneConfiguration(...'.
Error - typescript - src/webparts/2019/2019WebPart.ts(17,63): error TS2693: 'I2019WebPartProps' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
Error - typescript - src/webparts/2019/2019WebPart.ts(21,6): error TS2345: Argument of type '2019' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | StatelessComponent<{ description: any; }> | ComponentClass<{ description: any; }>'.
Error - typescript - src/webparts/2019/components/2019.tsx(5,52): error TS2693: 'I2019Props' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
Error - typescript - src/webparts/2019/components/2019.tsx(5,64): error TS2365: Operator '>' cannot be applied to types 'boolean' and 'Element'.
Error - typescript - src/webparts/2019/components/2019.tsx(8,11): error TS2322: Type '{ className: { container: string; row: string; column: string; 'ms-Grid': string; title: string; ...' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>'.
Error - typescript - src/webparts/2019/components/2019.tsx(8,31): error TS7027: Unreachable code detected.
Error - typescript - src/webparts/2019/components/2019.tsx(21,8): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'div'.
Error - 'typescript' sub task errored after 881 ms 
 TypeScript error(s) occurred.
```

I then decided to build a default webpart from a generator to investigate the dependencies.
However, I could not build from yo @microsoft/sharepoint

I have attempted to install older versions of sharepoint generator e.g. 1.6.0,1.7.0 or using node 8.17 but I still get errors on Typescript.

```
npm uninstall -g @microsoft/generator-sharepoint
npm install -g @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.6.0
yo @microsoft/sharepoint
```

Last Systems Config

```
/node/v10.19.0/lib
├── @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.10.0
├── gulp@3.9.1
├── npm@6.13.4
├── typescript@2.4.2
└── yo@2.0.2
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "2019",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gulp bundle",
    "clean": "gulp clean",
    "test": "gulp test"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "15.6.2",
    "react-dom": "15.6.2",
    "@types/react": "15.6.6",
    "@types/react-dom": "15.5.6",
    "@microsoft/sp-core-library": "~1.4.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base": "~1.4.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset": "~1.4.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core": "~1.4.0",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.1",
    "@types/es6-promise": "0.0.33"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "15.6.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@microsoft/sp-build-web": "~1.4.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-module-interfaces": "~1.4.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-workbench": "~1.4.1",
    "gulp": "~3.9.1",
    "@types/chai": "3.4.34",
    "@types/mocha": "2.2.38",
    "ajv": "~5.2.2"
  }
}
```

I want to install and develop on Sharepoint 2019 webparts, please advise how to make the sharepoint generator work ?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution,
A very silly Mistake!.

Do not Name your class with numbers.
try create a project using a letter first or 
Possible names

- sp2019
- _2019